# Why I cannot change status of the SonarQube roslyn issues?

Tags: permissions, sonarqube, roslyn

I cannot change the status of the `roslyn` issues, but I'm able to manage other:

[image: issues]

My user is allowed to administer issues and security hotspots:

- project:
  [image: project permissions]
- global:
  [image: global permissions]

Do you have an idea why I cannot change their status?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`roslyn` issues are not found by a Sonar-compatible analyzer (plugin), but by an external tool which imported them. Such rules are not managed by SonarQube which means you cannot change their status. You have to fix the issues or suppress them in the external analyzer tool configuration.

From the [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-issue/):

> There are a couple of limitations with importing external issues:
>
> - you can't manage them within SonarQube; for instance, there is no ability to mark them > False Positive.
> - you can't manage the activation of the rules that raise these issues within SonarQube. > External rules aren't visible on the Rules page or reflected in Quality Profiles.
>
> External issues and the rules that raise them must be managed in the configuration of your linter.